# Tips on using the with statement in Python

Tags: python, with-statement

Two questions regarding the with statement in Python. They come from a real-life problem so I keep it real. I am dealing with a pinch valve in order to control the flow in a pipe.

The program drives the valve with a class looking like that:

```
class Valve(object):
    """This class drives a pinch valve."""
    def __init__(self):
        self.close()
    def open(self):
        print('Open the valve.')
        self.state = 'opened'
    def close(self):
        print('Close the valve.')
        self.state = 'closed'
    def print_state(self):
        print('The valve is '+self.state+'.')
```

For some operations, I need exactly what the with statement does with a file (the file is closed at the end or if an error is raised), so I added a function to the class Valve and another class:

```
    def opened(self):
        return ContextManagerOpenedValve(self)

class ContextManagerOpenedValve(object):
    def __init__(self, valve):
        self.valve = valve
    def __enter__(self):
        self.valve.open()
        return self.valve
    def __exit__(self, type, value, traceback):
        self.valve.close()
```

Then these lines seem to work as I expected:

```
def do_something():
    print('For the sake of simplicity, this function does nothing.')

valve = Valve()

valve.print_state()
with valve.opened():
    valve.print_state()
    do_something()
valve.print_state()
```

My first question: what is the right way to obtain such result? Am I right to use the with statement for that? Can't I do that in a smarter way without defining the class ContextManagerOpenedValve?

Then I need to do something like this:
    USE_VALVE = False # or USE_VALVE = True

```
if USE_VALVE:
    with valve.opened():
        do_something()
else:
    do_something()
```

I dislike this solution since the function do_something is run anyway so it would be much nicer to avoid the repetition of "do_something()".

My second question: Is there a way to obtain the same result without
repeating do_something() twice ?

Comment: Please keep your questions to one per post; the conditional context manager part is a duplicate, for example.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sure, you can do it like so:

```
def valve_control(valve, use_value=False):
  if use_value:
    return ContextManagerOpenedValve(valve)
  else:
    return SomeFakeContextManager()
```

Then your call looks like:

```
with valve_control(value, USE_VALVE):
  do_something()
```